# Second feed_dict in sess.run(), Evaluation while training

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

The infamous:

```
*InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float and shape [100,8]
         [[Node: Placeholder_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[100,8], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]*
```

I've been training a CNN for awhile now. I've had separate python scripts for the training and evaluation method, and wanted to combine them. I want the network to train for N iterations, then run an evaluation, check if the model is better than any previous models, save if so, then resume training.

Since combining them, the network will train, but once it enters the "validation" part of the loop, it fails at the sess.run where I must feed_dict the validation data.

There are some debugging print("hi")s in the sess.run, the error appears on the line after the 3rd, but before the 4th "hi". This is where the feed_dict occurs for the validation data.

I've tried using both just the one graph, and also constructing a separate graph with it's own v_image_out, v_label_out, etc with no avail. I've been struggling with this error for days, changing so many things. Any help is greatly appreciated. The code has been modified to fit my purposes from this github: https://github.com/yeephycho/tensorflow_input_image_by_tfrecord/blob/master/src/flower_train_cnn.py

*EDIT: The precise line it calls the error is:

```
     File "train_cnn_4_pools.py", line 295, in train
        v_accuracy_out, v_logits_batch_out, v_summary = sess.run(
[accuracy, logits_batch, merged_summary_op],
 feed_dict={image_batch_placeholder: v_image_out, label_tensor_placeholder: `v_label_out})`
```

Caused by:

```
  File "train_cnn_4_pools.py", line 317, in <module>
    train()
  File "train_cnn_4_pools.py", line 226, in train
    label_batch_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[BATCH_SIZE, NUM_CLASSES])
```

This is extremely strange because I am calling the label_tensor_placeholder in the validation loop where it is failing. Not the label_batch_placeholder that the error is supposedly happening because of! Why would it try to call the wrong placeholder?!

```
def train():
image_batch_out, label_batch_out, filename_batch = input(if_eval = False)
v_image_batch_out, v_label_batch_out, v_filename_batch = input(if_eval = True)

image_batch_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[BATCH_SIZE, None, None, 3])
image_batch = tf.reshape(image_batch_out, (BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3))
v_image_batch = tf.reshape(v_image_batch_out, (BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3))

label_batch_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[BATCH_SIZE, NUM_CLASSES])
label_tensor_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[BATCH_SIZE])
label_offset = -tf.ones([BATCH_SIZE], dtype=tf.int64, name="label_batch_offset")
label_batch_one_hot = tf.one_hot(tf.add(label_batch_out, label_offset), depth=NUM_CLASSES, on_value=1.0, off_value=0.0)
label_batch = tf.add(label_batch_out, label_offset)
v_label_batch = tf.add(v_label_batch_out, label_offset)
with tf.variable_scope("inference") as scope:

    logits_out = network(image_batch)
    scope.reuse_variables()
    v_logits_out = network(v_image_batch)

logits_batch = tf.to_int64(tf.arg_max(v_logits_out, dimension = 1))
#loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=label_batch_one_hot, logits=logits_out))
prediction_op = tf.nn.softmax(logits_out)
v_prediction_op = tf.nn.softmax(v_logits_out)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(logits_batch, label_tensor_placeholder)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=label_batch_placeholder, predictions=prediction_op)
global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)

variable_summaries(prediction_op, name="Predictions")
surity_summary(prediction_op, name="Certainty")
#surity = surity_calc(prediction_op)
tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)
merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Visualize the graph through tensorboard.
    #file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("C:/logs", sess.graph)
    # op to write logs to Tensorboard
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_path, graph=tf.get_default_graph())
    accuracy_accu = 0
    best_accu = 0
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess, chk_path)
    saver.restore(sess, chk_path)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord, sess = sess)
    for epoch in range(1, 1000):
        for i in range(5):
            image_out, label_out, label_batch_one_hot_out, filename_out = sess.run([image_batch, label_batch_out, label_batch_one_hot, filename_batch])

            _, infer_out, loss_out, summary, predict_out, global_step_out = sess.run([train_step, logits_out, loss, merged_summary_op, prediction_op, global_step], feed_dict={image_batch_placeholder: image_out, label_batch_placeholder: label_batch_one_hot_out})


            #print(image_out.shape)
            print("label_out: ")
            #print(filename_out)
            print(label_out)
            #print(label_batch_one_hot_out)
            #print("infer_out: ")
            #print(infer_out)
            print("prediction: ")
            print(predict_out)
            print("loss: " + str(loss_out))
            print("local step: " + str(i))
            print("global step: " + str(global_step_out - 1))
            print("epoch: " + str(epoch))
            if(i%10 == 0):
                summary_writer.add_summary(summary, global_step_out)
        print("hi")
        for p in range(int(v_TRAINING_SET_SIZE/BATCH_SIZE)):
            print("hi")
            v_image_out, v_label_out, v_filename_out = sess.run([v_image_batch, v_label_batch, v_filename_batch])
            print("hi")
            v_accuracy_out, v_logits_batch_out, v_summary = sess.run([accuracy, logits_batch, merged_summary_op], feed_dict={image_batch_placeholder: v_image_out, label_tensor_placeholder: label_out})
            print("hi")
            accuracy_accu += accuracy_out

            print(p)
            print(v_image_out.shape)
            print("label_out: ")
            print(v_filename_out)
            print(v_label_out)
            print(v_logits_batch_out)
            print("accuracy: ", v_accuracy_out)
            summary_writer.add_summary(v_summary, p)

        print("Accuracy: ")
        print((accuracy_accu/TRAINING_SET_SIZE)*100)
        if(accuracy_accu > best_accu):
            saver.save(sess, chk_path)
            best_accu = accuracy_accu
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
    sess.close()
```

train()

Comment: Answered my own question: For anyone else having this issue, it turns out that the tf.summary part of the graph required the training labels placeholder! Removing that from the validation loop fixed the issue immediately, while adding adjusting the summary graph solved the problem. Sorry for cluttering SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question: For anyone else having this issue, it turns out that the tf.summary part of the graph required the training labels placeholder! Removing that from the validation loop fixed the issue immediately, while adding adjusting the summary graph solved the problem. Sorry for cluttering SO.